# fetching data of multiple text boxes within a single column of grid view

Tags: asp.net

How can I fetch the data of text boxes within a single column of a grid view from code behind?

```
<asp:GridView ID="CustomerOderGrid">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField Visible="false" DataField="ID"/> 
        <asp:BoundField DataField="NAME" HeaderText="NAME"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ORDER">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <input type="text" runat="server" id="BRAND"/>
                <input type="text" runat="server" id="QUANTITY"/>
                <input type="text" runat="server" id="TRANSPORTATION"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>    
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

How can I retrieve the values of text boxes `BRAND`, `QUANTITY` and `TRANSPORTATION` from code behind? I have created the DataTable in code behind "dt_Orders".

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`FindControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol) as follows:

```
var rows = CustomerOderGrid.Rows;
foreach (GridViewRow row in rows)
{
    var brand = ((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText)row.FindControl("BRAND")).Value;
    //other values
}
```

Note that you also need to add `runat="server"` to Gridview